# Stability of PDE Discretizations with Multistep Time Discretizations

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, stability, differential-equations

Let's pretend we have a spatially discretized PDE of the following form:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{u}^k}{\partial t^2} = D\boldsymbol{u}^k
\end{align}

where $D$ can be any form for now and $k$ refers to this being the discretization at time $t_k$. Then let's suppose, for example, we use a central difference approximation for the time derivative. We would then arrive at the following:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{u}^k}{\partial t^2} &= D\boldsymbol{u}^k \\
\frac{\boldsymbol{u}^{k+1} - 2\boldsymbol{u}^k + \boldsymbol{u}^{k-1}}{\Delta t^2} &= D\boldsymbol{u}^k \\
\boldsymbol{u}^{k+1} &= \left( 2I + \Delta t^2 D \right)\boldsymbol{u}^k - \boldsymbol{u}^{k-1}\\
\end{align}

Given the formulation above, how could one approach stability? First thoughts go to using Von Neumann stability analysis, but I have never seen it used in a vector-wise fashion such that one could take into account an arbitrary $D$ matrix. Any thoughts or references would be very useful.

**Edit**

The references provided in the comments were useful, but I found that only a few simple connections were needed to approach stability for this scenario. The key link was to take the expression above and cast it into a different difference equation with a more suitable form.

The more suitable case is by defining $\boldsymbol{w}^k = \left[(\boldsymbol{u}^{k})^{T}, (\boldsymbol{u}^{k-1})^{T}\right]^T$. We can than recast our difference equation into the form:

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{w}^{k+1} = G \boldsymbol{w}^k
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
G = \begin{bmatrix}
(2I + \Delta t^2 D) & -I \\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Then we know this system is stable if, given the set of eigenvalues $\lbrace \lambda_i \rbrace$ for $G$, the following holds:

\begin{align}
\max_{i} \left| \lambda_i\right| \lt 1
\end{align}

With these results, we can check whether some differential operator $D$ is going to be stable with a given time discretization, particularly if it uses older $\boldsymbol{u}$ states.

Comment: Do you not just need the eigenvalues of $(2I + \Delta t^2 D)$?

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson I don't believe that is correct since that alone doesn't weigh in contributions from the $\boldsymbol{u}^{k-1}$ term. I have seen Von Neumann stability analysis used in the non vector case for situations like this where we are using past solution values, but I am just unsure how to handle this more general vector case.

Comment: @C.Howard Have a look at section 4.6 of [this book](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/4all.pdf) by Nick Trefethen. For vector finite-difference formulas, the Von Neumann condition - theorem 4.10 - (a necessary, but not sufficient condition for discrete stability) is formulated in terms of the _spectral radius_ of the amplification _matrix_. There is a very interesting connection to _pseudo_-spectra (that I believe are one of the author's favourite research topics). See theorem 4.11 on page 181.

Comment: @GoHokies wow that is an excellent reference. It looks like this reference is what I need to approach stability in this context. I will make an update once I have things sorted out.

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here, http://samarskii.ru/books/book2001_2.pdf, page 428-... But it assumes something about the matrix $D$. Actually, I don't understand the necessity of considering the general case - are you aiming to solve a particular kind of PDE's or developing general theory? The more general is the theory, the less strong are results often.

Comment: @VorKir Thank you for the reference! I am actually looking into this for being able to analyze stability based on an unstructured mesh spatial discretization, resulting in some differential operator $D$. Assuming the unstructured mesh keeps $D$ from having some useful structure, I would still like to be able to, in a practical setting, get a feel for stability. I think with the references given, I have made the connections needed. I am just working it out on paper and doing some experiments to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a discussion of absolute stability of multistep methods for ODEs. See for example chapter 7 of LeVeque's book on finite difference methods .

Once you know the region of absolute stability for your time discretization, it's just a matter of checking that the eigenvalues of D (scaled by the time step) are inside that region. This is typical method-of-lines stability analysis.

The approach you've mentioned in your edit is equivalent, but in a sense less flexible since it doesn't separate the analysis of the time and space discretizations so clearly.   Also, the approach I'm recommending can be done entirely with pencil and paper.

Comment: You're definitely right. After I did my edit, I ended up stumbling on stability for multistep schemes and seeing how you could obtain the stability region just like in method of lines. This will certainly be the approach I take in the future after some further study. I also agree that it is nice to have separation of time and space when looking at stability.